# NoClassDefFoundError on grails run-app (Grails 2.5.0)

Tags: grails

When I try to run a freshly created project using Grails 2.5.0:

```
$ grails create-app test250
$ cd test250
$ grails run-app
```

I get the following error:

```
| Running Grails application
| Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.<clinit>(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:44)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
| Error     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
| Error     ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" 
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

My machine is running OSX 10.10.2 and I have several projects running on Grails 2.2.5 without problems.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  I would verify that GRAILS_HOME points to a proper uncorrupted installation and that $GRAILS_HOME/bin is on the PATH in front of any other location that might have a grails executable in it.  If you can't get it straightened out, please file an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS.  Thanks.

Comment: I use gvm to manage Grails and I don't see the problem there.  I just now used the command at https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/92e141ac5f58de7a0271 to test the distribution and I don't see the problem there either.

Comment: GRAILS_HOME points to a fresh installation and it is the only installation in the PATH variable. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't yet make sense to me and I haven't been able to reproduce it.  I believe it is happening, I just don't know how to make it happen.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we can track it and maybe we can pin it down.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Just for the record, when I change the dependency resolver on BuildConfig from maven to ivy the error changes:

| Error 2015-03-31 17:40:34,812 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: org/springframework/expression/ParserContext
    Line | Method
->>  800 | defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
...

Comment: The same test works without errors on a Windows 7 machine. Do you use any tool like vagrant to test the distribution on different environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) (as pointed by Jeff) to manage the different Grails versions installed on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that commons-logging is indirectly used by the Tomcat plugin (`ForkedTomcatServer` extends the Grails `ForkedGrailsProcess` class which references `org.apache.commons.logging.Log`) but it's not exported, and it's not a Grails dependency.

It is an indirect dependency of the asset-pipeline plugin, so that should make the jar available and work around the bug for most users. Did you remove asset-pipeline as a dependent plugin in BuildConfig.groovy?

You should be able to get things working by explicitly adding a dependency for commons-logging in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
   runtime 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
   ...
}
```

Comment: "Did you remove asset-pipeline as a dependent plugin in BuildConfig.groovy?" - His description says that he ran create-app and then ran run-app.  If there was editing of BuildConfig.groovy between those steps, there are several ways the problem could have been introduced.  I wonder if that is what happened.

Comment: As Jeff said, I didn't touched the application after the create-app. The error persisted even after explicitly adding the dependency as Burt suggested.

Comment: The only "different" thing that I did was to set JAVA_HOME (and PATH) to an installation of the 1.7.0_21 version in order to remove this warning: objc[37872]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstr‌​ument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.